# Python: image not showing when start programs

Tags: python

Whn i run this my sprite image dose not show

```
from tkinter import *
import sys, time, os

moveSpeed = 5
#stops error with holding keys down
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
X = 396
Y = 281
def cen(name, w = 500, h = 100):
    ws = name.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = name.winfo_screenheight()
    # calculate position x, y
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    name.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
def up(event):
    global Y, X
    #checks if in play area then moves by the amount set
    if Y > 0:
        print("Y = ",Y)
        Y-= moveSpeed
        X = X
        sprite.place(x = X, y = Y)
        game.mainloop()
def down(event):
    global Y, X
    #checks if in play area then moves by the amount set
    if Y < 421:
        print("Y = ",Y)
        Y+= moveSpeed
        X = X
        sprite.place(x = X, y = Y)
        game.mainloop()
def left(event):
    global Y, X
    #checks if in play area then moves by the amount set
    if X > -10:
        print("X = ",X)
        Y = Y
        X-= moveSpeed
        sprite.place(x = X, y = Y)
        game.mainloop()
def right(event):
    global Y, X
    #checks if in play area then moves by the amount set
    if X < 431:
        print("X = ",X)
        Y= Y
        X+= moveSpeed
        sprite.place(x = X, y = Y)
        game.mainloop()
game = Tk()
cen(game, 500, 500)
backgroundImage = PhotoImage(file="background.png")
background = Label(game, image=backgroundImage).pack()
spriteture = PhotoImage(file="sprite.gif")
sprite = Label(game, image=spriteture)
sprite.place(x = X, y = Y)
sprite.pack()
game.bind('<Up>',        up)
game.bind('<Down>',  down)
game.bind('<Left>',  left)
game.bind('<Right>',  right)
game.mainloop()
```

When i start this game it gives the image does not start out visabile until i push an arrow key
when you push an arrow it moves the sprite
it does not give me any errors so i am confused 
please help

Comment: Could it be related to a garbage collection problem? http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Comment: what do you mean @MarcusMøller ?

Comment: I did a quick search on Google, but it does not sound like that's the problem, as the image is still shown in some cases.

Comment: Your code works fine on my end. The sprite image is shown on start up. Have you tried using other images for debugging?

Comment: i will try changing the image

Comment: I think your use of `sprite.pack()` might be messing with your placement. Try to comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

The Probelm is i am packing the image when i dont need to

so i need to get rid of

```
sprite.pack()
```

Comment: Yes, there are principally three geometry-layout-managers in Tkinter **`{ place | grid | pack }`** and each has more of it's own methods. You may choose whichever suits best your layout-setup, however once used, you shall not mix it with any other ( up until a last `.*_forget()` / `.destroy()` method ). The same applies to "neighbouring"-Widgets that share the same "container"-widget. So be carefull on your code design & enjoy the great powers of Tkinter GUI concept.